# Is Script# working with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, script#

Hi I wanted to use script# with vs2013 but i cant install extension. Because my Vs is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i needed to download repo from https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp
And build solution to solve this.

Comment: I was able to compile the solution using vs2013 but I got an error in vs2015. However if you want the extension to work in vs2015 you need to add in the manifest file '\src\ZipX\VSIX\Extension.vsixmanifest' the following:
      <VisualStudio Version="14.0">
        <Edition>Enterprise</Edition>
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
        <Edition>Community</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>

Answer (score 2):

Install Script# using the Nuget package manager from within vs2013.